# Bison semantic rules variable

Tags: c, bison, lex

I am having trouble with this Bison program. It has to receive a string of 1s and 0s with a period like "101.101" by multiplying them by 2^n. For example:

```
"101.101" = (1*2^2)+(0*2^1)+(1*2^0)+(1*2^-1)+(0*2^-2)+(1*2^-3)=5.625
```

The point tells when the pow is positive or negative. I have the following semantic actions:

```
S→ L.R 
 S→ L  
 L → L1 B   
 L → B  
 R → R1 B  
 R → B   
 B→ 0  
 B → 1  
 Sematic Rules  
 L.pos=0;R.pos=-1;S.val=L.val+R.val  
 L.pos=0;S.val=L.val;  
 L1.pos = L.pos + 1; B.pos = L.pos; L.val = L1.val + B.val;  
 B.pos = L.pos; L.val = B.val;  
 R1.pos = R.pos - 1; B.pos = R.pos; L.val = L1.val + B.val;
 B.pos = R.pos; L.val = B.val;  
 B.val=0;  
 B.val = 1*2^B.pos;
```

the problem I am having right now is that I don't know why the .pos variables aren't working, they are always valued to 0. My bison code is :

```
%{
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
void yyerror (char *string);

%}
%union {
    struct named_for_discussion_below {
        int pos;
        int val;
    } pair;
}

%token DOT
%token ZERO
%token ONE
%token l1
%token r1
%type <pair> b l r s;


%%
x: s {/*printf(" the number is %d \n",$1);*/}
 ;

s: l DOT r {$1.pos=0;$3.pos=-1;$$.val=$1.val+$3.val;/*printf(" the both numbers are %d and       %d\n",$1,$3);*/}
| l {$1.pos=0;$$.val=$1.val;/*printf(" the numbers is %d \n",$1);*/}
 ;

 l: l b {$1.pos = $$.pos + 1; $2.pos = $$.pos; $$.val = $1.val + $2.val;printf(" the   number is left,  l pos is %d and l val is %d \n", $$.pos, $$.val);}
| b   {$1.pos = $$.pos; $$.val = $1.val;printf(" the number is left,  l pos is %d and l  val is %d \n", $$.pos, $$.val);}
 ;

r: r b {$1.pos = $$.pos - 1; $2.pos = $$.pos; $$.val = $1.val + $2.val;printf(" the number     is right, r pos is %d and r val is %d \n", $$.pos, $$.val);}
| b   {$1.pos = $$.pos; $$.val = $1.val; printf(" the number is right, r pos is %d and r val is %d \n", $$.pos, $$.val);}

 ;

b: ZERO {$$.val = 0; printf(" the number is 0, val is %d and pos is %d \n",$$.val,$$.pos);}
| ONE {$$.val = 1*2^($$.pos); printf(" the number is 1, val is %d and pos is %d  \n",$$.val,$$.pos);}
 ;

%%
#include "lex.yy.c"

void yyerror (char *string){
  printf ("%s",string);
}

int main (){

    yyparse();
}
```

and the lex file is:

```
%{
#include <stdio.h>
#include <math.h>
#include "y.tab.h"
%}
BINARY [0-1]
%%
"1" {return ONE;}
"0" {return ZERO;}
"." {return DOT;}
%%
```

Answer (score 1):

Attributes in yacc are always synthesized attributes, with values that propagate up from the leaves to the root of the parse tree, not down.

If you want to use inherited attributes, you need to use a tool like [btyacc](http://www.siber.com/btyacc/) (you can get an updated version [here](https://github.com/ChrisDodd/btyacc)).  This allows you to write your code like:

```
%{
#include <string.h>
#include <stdio.h>
#include<stdlib.h>
%}
%union {
    double  val;
    int     pos;
}

%token DOT
%token ZERO
%token ONE
%token l1
%token r1
%type <val> b(<pos>) l(<pos>) r(<pos>) s;


%%
x: s {printf(" the number is %f \n",$1);}
 ;

s: l(0) DOT r(-1) {$$=$1+$3; /*printf(" the both numbers are %f and %f\n",$1,$3);*/}
 | l(0) {$$=$1; /*printf(" the numbers is %f \n",$1);*/}
 ;

l($pos): l($pos+1) b($pos) { $$ = $1 + $2; printf(" the   number is left,  l pos is %d and l val is %f \n", $pos, $$);}
       | b($pos)   { $$ = $1; printf(" the number is left,  l pos is %d and l  val is %f \n", $pos, $$);}
       ;

r($pos): b($pos) r($pos-1) { $$ = $1 + $2; printf(" the number     is right, r pos is %d and r val is %f \n", $pos, $$);}
       | b($pos)   { $$ = $1; printf(" the number is right, r pos is %d and r val is %f \n", $pos, $$);}
       ;

b($pos): ZERO { $$ = 0; printf(" the number is 0, val is %f and pos is %d \n",$$,$pos);}
       | ONE { $$ = pow(2.0, $pos); printf(" the number is 1, val is %f and pos is %d  \n",$$,$pos);}
       ;

%%
#include "lex.yy.c"

void yyerror (const char *string, ...){
  printf ("%s",string);
}

int main (){
    yyparse();
}
```

Note that I also changed `val` to be a `double` as `int` can only hold integers.  I also changed it to use `pow` for exponentiation (`^` in C is xor).

Answer (score 0):

In your actions, you want to be assign to $$ from $1 and $2. So, $$ should be on the left hand side of the '=', $1 and $2 on the right. So...

```
l: l b {$1.pos = $$.pos + 1; $2.pos = $$.pos; $$.val = $1.val + $2.val;printf(" the   number is left,  l pos is %d and l val is %d \n", $$.pos, $$.val);}
             ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
    | b   {$1.pos = $$.pos; $$.val = $1.val;printf(" the number is left,  l pos is %d and l  val is %d \n", $$.pos, $$.val);}
           ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^ 
     ;
```

There are several others of the same variety.

```
r: r b {$1.pos = $$.pos - 1; $2.pos = $$.pos; $$.val = $1.val + $2.val;printf(" the number     is right, r pos is %d and r val is %d \n", $$.pos, $$.val);}
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
| b   {$1.pos = $$.pos; $$.val = $1.val; printf(" the number is right, r pos is %d and r val is %d \n", $$.pos, $$.val);}
        ^^^^^^^^^^^^^^^
```

I'm not clear on what exactly your expressions should be, but $$ should be a function of $1 and $2.

Comment: the problem I have is that .pos should tell me the position that the token is, and instead, it just stays at 0, and never really changes its number. This is needed so that it can no how many numbers are to the left of the point and rise them to the correct power for example 101 should know that its positions are 1 is position 2, 0 is positino 1, and 1 is position 0, so that it can multiply them like 1*2^(position)

Answer (score 0):

The `$$` is the *result* of the semantic operation, so having it as the source of an assignment makes no sense. Also, you can't pass values down the chain, you have to use other methods to pass values to more basic rules (like global variables).